# Does Font of Life grant a saving throw against enervation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats

The general feat Font of Life has as its benefit the following:

> Whenever you are struck by an attack that drains energy or bestows negative levels, **you gain an immediate saving throw to resist the effect at the standard Difficulty Class of the attack.** If this initial save is successful, you avoid any negative levels but you still suffer any other effects of the attack or spell. If this save fails, the attack proceeds as if this roll had never been made (meaning you still receive whatever save to which you’re normally entitled). (*Heroes of Horror* 122-3)

Emphasis mine, but what does that mean?

> #### Example 1
>
> Abe is slammed by a [wight](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/wight.htm), which has the supernatural ability energy drain:
>
> > Living creatures hit by a wight’s slam attack gain one negative level. The DC is 14 for the Fortitude save to remove a negative level. The save DC is Charisma-based. For each such negative level bestowed, the wight gains 5 temporary hit points. (*MM* 255)
>
> **What does the feat Font of Life enable Abe to do?**
>
> ---
>
> #### Example 2
>
> Abe is struck by the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*enervation*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/enervation.htm) [necro] (*PH* 226):
>
> > You point your finger and utter the incantation, releasing a black ray of crackling negative energy that suppresses the life force of any living creature it strikes. You must make a ranged touch attack to hit. If the attack succeeds, the subject gains 1d4 negative levels. [...] Assuming the subject survives, it regains lost levels after a number of hours equal to your caster level (maximum 15 hours). Usually, negative levels have a chance of permanently draining the victim’s levels, but the negative levels from enervation don’t last long enough to do so.
>
> **If the necromancer rolls a 4, what does the feat Font of Life enable Abe to do?**

In Example 1, I assume Abe makes a Fortitude saving throw (DC 14) immediately upon being slammed. Success means he suffers no effects of the energy drain but is still dealt the wight's slam damage. Failure means Abe suffers both the effects of the energy drain *and* the wight's slam damage. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. However, in Example 2, because of the feat Font of Life, does Abe get a saving throw despite the spell *enervation* having an entry of *Saving Throw: None*?

#### "Who cares? No one ever takes this feat anyway"

My level 8 barbarian (in a party with inconsistent access to the spell [*death ward*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/deathWard.htm)) *is* considering the feat, given the potential commonality of the spell *enervation* and his inability to defend against it. Although the campaign's wealth by level is average (or even slightly above) the *DMG*'s guidelines, a permanent *death ward* effect is still a long way off. His massive Fortitude saving throw bonus doesn't help him against negative levels until 24 hours later, which is too long to wait if a vampire's beating the crap out of the party *now*, and he's a *dead* barbarian after the second lucky *enervation* spell from the boss necromancer.

Answer (score 6):

1) Yes. Abe would make a Fortitude Save at DC 14 to avoid the negative level via the feat. If he fails, then he takes both the damage and the negative level. If he succeeds, he does not take the negative level, but still takes the damage.

As the Energy Drain of the wraith is (Su), the SRD says this ([link](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities)):

> The saving throw (if any) against a supernatural ability is:
>
> 10 + 1/2 the creature’s HD + the creature’s ability modifier (usually Charisma).

2) Yes. As the feat says:

> you gain an immediate saving throw to resist the effect at the standard Difficulty Class of the attack

Under Saving Throws ([link](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#partial)):

> **None**
>
> No saving throw is allowed.

Additionally, it also says ([link](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#object)):

> **Saving Throw Difficulty Class**
>
> A saving throw against your spell has a DC of 10 + the level of the spell + your bonus for the relevant ability (Intelligence for a wizard, Charisma for a sorcerer or bard, or Wisdom for a cleric, druid, paladin, or ranger). A spell’s level can vary depending on your class. Always use the spell level applicable to your class.

Even though *Enervation* does not normally allow a saving throw, it still would have a (standard) DC as set by the above point, which be the DC you would use for *Font of Life*.

Example - Necromancer casts *Enervation*:

- Touch Attack Hits

  - *Font of Life* activates:

    - Successful Save - Negative levels ignored
    - Failed Save - Negative levels apply as normal (there is no saving throw for *Enervation* here)
  - Other spell effects applied (there are none for *Enervation*)
- Touch Attack Misses

  - No effect

Comment: But *enervation* doesn’t **have** a standard Difficulty Class. Save-allowing 4th-level spells do, but *enervation* isn’t one of those, and *enervation* is the attack that was actually made. The formula for saving throw DC is listed in the [Saving Throw section of Spell Descriptions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#savingThrow), which does not apply to *enervation*.

Comment: (or, to be more accurate, the argument above is the one you have to refute; it may be wrong and you may be right, but the burden of proof is on you there – the answer as-is does not refute it)

Comment: Oooh I see. I somehow missed the "of the attack" part. Now I'm not sure if that even exists since like you said it doesn't have a DC...I'll see if I can find anything about that.

Comment: Hm, the only thing I can find is that the description of "None" for saving throw only specifies that "No saving throw is allowed." Since there is a separate section stating: "A saving throw against your spell has a DC of 10 + the level of the spell + your bonus for the relevant ability (Intelligence for a wizard, Charisma for a sorcerer or bard, or Wisdom for a cleric, druid, paladin, or ranger). A spell’s level can vary depending on your class. Always use the spell level applicable to your class," do you think that would be enough to argue that it still has a DC, it just isn't used?

Comment: Maybe; definitely better than nothing. Why not put it up and see what the community thinks (via votes)?

Comment: +1 Save DCs follow a standard formula, whether for spells or abilities. This is clearly the intent of the feat.

Comment: @mbocek If it was “clear,” a question wouldn’t have been necessary. Please be more considerate with your comments, and avoid belittling those who ask questions that are “clear” to you. In this particular case, HeyICanChan has exceptionally strong knowledge of the rules, and yet felt that this question was worth asking; you should give him the benefit of the doubt and assume he had good reason to be unsure. You should, in fact, do this for all querents.

Comment: @KRyan I apologize, you are right. What I meant to say is that firedraco's answer has hit the mark exactly.

Comment: @mbocek Indeed; it’s an easy linguistic pattern to fall into, which is all the more reason I think it’s important to mention it even when I suspect no malice (and also because I think some in this community *do* exhibit malice with similar phrasing, but that’s a separate issue and doesn’t apply here).

Comment: @mbocek I took no offense, but, yeah, just because a saving throw *can* be determined for an effect, if a feat gives a character a saving throw against an effect for which there is normally **no** saving throw, the feat should probably say so with a bit more confidence. Also, note that there is *no* standard DC for the wight's attack--it makes an attack roll, you take negative levels; we're inferring that it means the DC to remove. Finally, I've heard that *Heroes of Horror* is filled with [apparent errors](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?153557-Heroes-of-Horror-Errata-(3-5)).

Comment: Added the comment about saving throws for spells. Trying to see if there is anything that has a "standard" saving throw for monster attacks.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hah! DragoonWraith (original poster of that thread) is me. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: Standard saving throw for (Su) monster attacks: "10 + ½ the creature’s HD + the creature’s ability modifier (usually Charisma)". ([source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities))

Comment: Ooh, I had seen that but somehow missed that Energy Drain is an Su attack. I'll add that in there.